# Extract 100+ input data from a POST'ed form with jsp: any better approaches?

Tags: java, forms, jsp

A servlet that I am writing needs to access all 100+ POST parameters (filled in by a form): the parameters are different by type (text, option, select, etc.).
With the parameters taken in the correct order, the servlet constructs some instances of `@Entity` objects that will be later persisted in a database using `JPA`.

Is there a more intuitive way to map post parameters values to `@Entity` objects instead of cycling over `HTTPServletRequest.getParametersMap()` and saving those values into temporary variables in order to create objects?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, from using reflection to using some framework (Spring MVC, JAX-RS, etc) that does it for you. What have you investigated so far?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like struts?

Comment: Why wouldn't you break them to separate JSON's on client & map them with Jackson?

Answer (score 3):

If you make sure that the entity bean property names match exactly the request parameter names, then you could use [`BeanUtils#populate()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) of [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) for that.

```
BeanUtils.populate(entity, request.getParameterMap());
```

That's all.

To get a step further, you can adopt a MVC framework which transparently maps request parameters to bean properties (the *model*) for you based on how the *view* is composed (even along with transparent conversion, validation and invoking bean action methods!), such as [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) or [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-mvc/info).